# How do I set up a Spring Quartz job on a method marked as @Transactional?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, applicationcontext, transactional

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE and Quartz 1.8.5.  I’m trying to set up a Quartz job to execute a method on a class marked as @Transactional.  Below is the interface …

```
public interface MyDataService
{
    …
    void downloadAndProcessMyDataMatchedFiles();
```

and here is the implementing class …

```
@Service("MyDataService")
@Transactional
public class MyDataServiceImpl extends AbstractCleverUserService implements MyDataService
{
    …
    @Override
    public void downloadAndProcessMyDataMatchedFiles()
    {
    …
```

I have this set up in my dispatcher-servlet.xml file …

```
<bean id="processMatchedDatasFileJob"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="MyDataService" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="downloadAndProcessMyDataMatchedFile" />
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="processMatchedDatasCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="processMatchedDatasFileJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="${process.matched.students.schedule}" />
</bean>
```

However, I get this error …

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processMatchedDatasFileJob' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy530.downloadAndProcessMyDataMatchedFile()
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:618)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas how to get my Quartz job working with the least amount of effort as possible?

Comment: Have you considered implementing a proxy object around the transactional bean? By that I mean another class which implements `MyDataService` and simply delegates all calls to the actual transactional bean. Then you can set the quartz job on the proxy object.

Comment: The spring setup looks ok for me. Except that you have typo in the value="downloadAndProcessMyDataMatchedFile"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method name is not spelled correctly, please change the

`<property name="targetMethod" value="downloadAndProcessMyDataMatchedFile"/>`

into

`<property name="targetMethod" value="downloadAndProcessMyDataMatchedFiles"/>`